# Why Lambert's law does not hold for photoresistors?

Tags: solid-state-chemistry, semiconductors, light

Why don't  photoresistors made of Si obey [Lambert's cosine law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert%27s_cosine_law)? Is it related to the dark current of the photoresistor? I couldn't find any solution while searching the web.

Comment: Address this rather to Physics SE (particularly solid state/phase physics). The fact chemistry deals with various compounds and their electrons does not mean anything related to that is addressed by chemistry. // Aside of that and generally, be aware that laconic, not elaborated questions  (describe well, search, think, refer, summarize) are usually closed on the StackExchange network.

Comment: I wouldn't agree this is off-topic for Chemistry.SE. Besides, Physics.SE already have unanswered [Why do some materials follow Lambert's cosine law?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/172346) and the info on the underlying principles indeed seems to be scarce. I do agree though that the question is too laconic. A reference, an example of such material, or elaboration on the expected chemical effect on radiometry would improve the question.

Comment: @andselisk I have commented rather in sense Physics SE may be better, but have not checked the site for this. I do agree the solid state matter is a cross-discipline between both, but considering the Q asks rather about physical aspects.

Comment: Not sure if there are Si [photoresistors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photoresistor#Applications). They are usually metal sulphides/selenides.

Comment: @Poutnik - plenty of silicon  photoresistors out there to be bought (although photoresistors are themselves a pretty niche product anymore).

Comment: @JonCuster Hmm, interesting, never heard of Si LDR, unless the components  are photodiodes/transistors.

Comment: Why is the material being silicon important for this question? Is it claimed somewhere that silicon photoresistors are special in their reflection directivity pattern?